# How to display stereo photosphere in Gear VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I am following [this tutorial](http://bernieroehl.com/360stereoinunity/) to view Stereo image in Unity3D. Unfortunately it only covers Oculus Rift and Google Cardboard. Both of there SDKs have two separate cameras for left eye and right eye. Here is a summary of how to do it:

1. Create 2 spheres for both eyes and place them at origin.
2. Put them in different layers (left and right).
3. Set culling mask of each camera (left eye and right eye) to left layer and right layer respectively.

**PROBLEM:**

In Gear VR camera setup, Oculus SDK is using only one camera component which is on `CenterEyeAnchor` child of `OVRCameraRig`:

[image]

I  don't know how to apply the above procedure in this case. I know there are 2 transforms LelftEyeAnchor and RightEyeAnchor which are used for stereo view but I don't if camera component is attached to them at runtime in Android build. Is there a way to achieve stereo rendering for this setup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a working demo, but i can't acces to my repo until tomorrow, if no one answer you i will post it tomorrow.

Comment: @cjf93 Thanks a lot. is it for Gear VR Oculus sdk?

Comment: Yes my project is for Samsung Gear VR, its the same right?

Comment: yes it is. But it should work with one camera setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have:

[image: Unity Hierarchy]

With LeftEyeAnchor and RightEyeAnchor being on their layers (Left, Right).
Then I have an empty Gameobject: Stero, containing 2 cameras.

This is the set up for the **Left**

[image]

I have multiple layers on the culling mask because im displaying some stuff on each eye but you need to set there the layers being seen by the camera.

Its the same for the other camera **changing every Left for Right**

And at the end, currently disable because i enable both via script, the 2 spheres, one in one layer and the other in the other layer.

The **CenterEyeAnchor have Both eyes as a target**, and **left and right layers are in the culling mask** too

Hope it helps!

Comment: which one to set as main camera?

Comment: I have the 3 cameras in the scene tagged as mainCamera

Comment: And all 3 cameras have same depth?

Comment: Yes, im glad i help you solve the problem, im really new here on stackokverflow :D